# How to get exact frequencies in the time response using InverseFourier?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have amplitude data varying with frequency for a signal. From that I want to generate time response in such a way so that if I take `Fourier` I can get the amplitude data back.  I have written down the code to get time response based on this [answer.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185234/generate-noise-time-series-with-given-datas-psd/185246#185246)

```
amplitude = ConstantArray[0, 1000];
amplitude[[{50}]] = {100};
fz = Table[i, {i, 1000, 10^6, 1000}];
amplitude2 = 
  Flatten[{amplitude, 
    Reverse[Conjugate[amplitude[[Range[2, Length[amplitude]]]]]]}];
OP = InverseFourier[amplitude2, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
timeresponse = Re[OP];

ListPlot[Transpose[{fz, amplitude}], Mesh -> All, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, Joined -> True, 
 TicksStyle -> Large]
ListPlot[timeresponse[[Range[2, Length[timeresponse]]]], 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full, TicksStyle -> Large]
ListPlot[Abs[Fourier[timeresponse, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]][[
  1 ;; Length[amplitude]]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 TicksStyle -> Large]
```

[image: Fz-Amp and time response]

Actually I have very complex freq-amplitude data. In which various amplitude values are there for a large range of frequencies.
How I can tell Mathematica that these values of amplitude are related with these harmonics of certain frequencies?

Answer (score 1):

Actually here frequency information is not being fed to the `InverseFourier`. What `fz` you are giving that is just being used for information.

`InverseFourier` just have amplitude vector. Means value of amplitudes, with corresponding element number. If you scale whole output `timeresponse` on the time axis by frequency step^-1 (1000 in your case), than automatically you will get required time signal and then frequencies in that signal will be matching with your given amplitude-frequency data. Here is signal with 1 ms with 2000 data points.

And also multiply with the length of amplitude vector, that will give you right

`OP = Length[amplitude]*InverseFourier[amplitude2, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]`
Just see here.
[image: Time response]